# How to delete a file after downloading it with Response->download() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, download, controller, delete-file

I have generated a CSV file using fputcsv() and then I return the downloaded file from the controller. It successfully downloads via the browser but I also want to delete the file after it is downloaded.

```
//controller class
public function downloadCSV{
...
    return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
}
```

How am I able to call my delete function.

```
//controller class
csvService->deleteCSV($fileName);

//csvService class
public function deleteCSV($filename) {
    if (File::exists(storage_path($filename))) {
          File::delete(storage_path($filename));
    }
}
```

I have tried the following. The file does not download but it is successfully deleted.

```
public function downloadCSV(...)
    ...
    response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);

    return $csvService->deleteCSV($fileName);
}
```

Comment: you need to use queues: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `deleteFileAfterSend` method:

```
return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

[File Download and Responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads)

```
//controller class
public function downloadAndDeleteCSV{
    ...
    return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```